# Use global variable inside function?

Tags: php

I'm having trouble figuring out this in php.

I have a variable called $user that holds the user name.

In my function I need to make use of this variable:

```
function test($message) {
    echo "user: $user, message: $message";
}
```

I only know how to do it by passing $user to the function each time I'm calling it, but i'm in a particular situation in which I cannot do it. So, how can I use a variable defined outside my function inside of it?

Comment: See global. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to avoid using global variables if possible. But `$GLOBALS['user']` will return the global value of `$user` from inside your function.  Or if you use `global $user;`, `$user` will be defined from its global value within your function.

Comment: The main reason is for when an application grows and gets larger, it pollutes the namespace.  Classes and functions are built to contain sets of logic and variables.  If you use don't use this practice, variables will start to overlap and cause problems (how can you remember every single variable in your application?).  http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad